# Facebook Unity deep linking doesn't work

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, deep-linking

I sent a request out using `FB.AppRequest` and I got this on my iPad:

```
Request Sent {"to":["54742366872XXXX"],"request":"1521526728123676"}
```

And when I opened the App by tap my Facebook notification on iPod, and called deep linking. I got this:

```
fb170085486532707://authorize/#target_url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fappcenter%2Fjbislands%3Ffbs%3D1001%26request_ids%3D322759461248823%252C333157203553454%26ref%3Dnotif%26app_request_type%3Duser_to_user
```

I don't see any connection between those number. And when I run what Facebook example:

```
void DeepLinkCallback(FBResult response) {
if(response.Text != null) {
    var index = (new Uri(response.Text)).Query.IndexOf("request_ids");
    if(index != -1) {
        // ...have the user interact with the friend who sent the request,
        // perhaps by showing them the gift they were given, taking them
        // to their turn in the game with that friend, etc.
    }
}
```

I always get `-1` for index. Can anyone tell me how to read this deep link thing?

Comment: I found out what really happen, it was because the Facebook App user didn't proper authorise the app. So right after, I authorise it, I get something like this:

`fb170085486532707://authorize/#access_token=CAACasR0BmGMBAA9NguUHFz8GgBANubp6uXMgyiMs2trrA1ueYaCPVVRcplHjeEQcJXqEZC6V3VtTeUUXsKEgt0Jx0zjzSOTiXxLXxgM1bLM5qNoR8FYzsYyzRvkoZAffLcAKeCVBKlDiJicC1yATmvKNsZCdL5Px9BeGx1HZAQ6FlBPr9JUxDesFBDapDgqJRArticWySn3iCZBu0AWqJktH3FMhXXXXXX&expires_in=3600`

Does anyone know where to go from here?